# What is the timeline for the first Season of Maria Watches Over Us?

Tags: maria-sama-ga-miteru

In Episodes 7, 8 and 9 of *Maria-sama ga Miteru (Maria Watches Over Us)*, they are set around Valentines Day. it's stated that at around this time Rosa Chinensis (Yōko Mizuno), Rosa Gigantea (Sei Satō) and Rosa Foetida (Eriko Torii) took their final exams and were waiting on their university selections which Sei got hers first and got her first choice and their graduations approching.

In Episodes 10 and 11 the events are set during Christmas where Sei's and Shiori Kubo relationship is revealed. in one scene Sei's and her petite sœur Shimako Tōdō are talking about Christmas and Sei makes reference to the upcoming exams.

When i saw the preview for Episode 12 it seems to carry on from the last part of Episode 9  with Yumi Fukuzawa and Sachiko Ogasawara are going on their date they had planned after Valentines Day.

I am wondering, what exactly is the timeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The episode numbers relate to the order they were broadcast. chronologically speaking in the series Episodes 7, 8 and 9 occur after Episodes 10 and 11 with Episode 12 occurring after 9.

According to the linear notes in the bonus menu of the RightStuf DVD (Disk 3), the Valentines Day Episodes were aired earlier as the initial broadcast date for Episode 7 fell on/around February 14 which is Valentines Day.

Because the 3 Valentines Day Episodes are tightly connected together in terms of plot they couldn't just broadcast episode 7 and be done with it so the 3 episodes was broadcast in sequence and 10 and 11 broadcast after before the conclusion of the first season.